# which pets are Tank pets in Cube World?

Tags: cube-world

I was wondering what pets were Tank pets in Cube World.  I know turtles are, but I would like to know if there are some more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Turtles](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Turtle) are the **only tank pet currently available**.

For a full list of pets and types (which does contain spoilers in the form of taming foods) [see here](http://wiki.cubeworldforum.org/index.php?title=Pets#Pet_Types).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a level 10 Water Mage, and I have a Snout Beetle at level 9.  He can absorb hits, get the aggro, and deal damage with power attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Although other pets can be pretty tanky, the turtle is the only pet that is classed as a "Tank"

To be honest though you can make any pet tanky by just upgrading your pet master skill.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, turtles are the only tank pets. You can tame them with a cinnamon roll. They are found near rivers and ponds. So yes, right now, turtles are the only tameable tank animals in Cube World.

Answer (score -3):

Turtles, porcupines (?) and most beetles.

Comment: not beetles. Ive gone through most of them and they are definitely not tanks. Turtles are the only tank pet right now